# Uitableview sort numerically

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, numerical

Long story short, I have begun working with uitableview a not long ago. I finally got everything down except for proper sorting.

I can sort ascending and descending but not numerically

I have been told that I need to use nsdictionary or nsnumber and compare results to sort proper

In other words I have the nsmutablearray numberArray... And it adds numbers but in string format so  the numbers  25, 32, 15 and 3 will show in the view as, 32, 3, 25 and 15.

I have looked and read for hours, hours of testing with different codes and such nix any get any results... Can anyone please direct me?

Comment: so shizam, thank you for the reply,was exactly what I needed.. now I ran into a second problem,,, I currently have 2 nsmutable arrays, 1: nameArray, 2: scoreArray, and of course it is sorting accoring to score., my next issue is this, the name stays in the position of input, it doesnt get sorted with the proper score, so say i have three players, player1: Tom: score 23, ;player 2 Tim, score 15 and player 3: paul score 35,, it shows like this: Tom: 35, Tim 23, Paul 15, when it should be showing like this,, Paul 35, Tom 23, Tim 15.... is there a way to sort that? or shouls i use 1 array instead?

Comment: You should probably use an NSDictionary with key -> value of name -> score (or vice versa), then you could use [dictionary allKeys], [dictionary allValues] and map back and forth between them using [array indexOfObject] or [array objectForIndex] accordingly from whatever sorted array you have.  If you have further questions you should ask as a proper question though to avoid discussions in comments :)

Comment: sounds good, ill see what I figure out! thank you very much, and sorry for the question in comment, I'm new to this forum stuff, wasn't sure how it worked. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort on 'intValue' of the strings:

```
NSMutableArray *toBeSorted = [NSMutableArray array];
...add stuff to the array...
NSSortDescriptor *mySorter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"intValue" ascending:YES] autorelease];
[toBeSorted sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mySorter]];
```

So while the above will work, tc's suggestion of using:

```
toBeSorted = [toBeSorted sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

is a more elegant solution.

Comment: `[a sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]` is more likely to do the "right thing".

Comment: Wouldn't that still sort as if the items were strings?  He is trying to sort the strings as if they were numbers (ints)

Comment: It does "Finder-like" sorting, which IME sorts numbers within strings numerically (it probably compares with `NSNumericSearch`). It should handle "foo2" and "foo10" and also doesn't create loads of temporary objects (which KVC might do).

Comment: Ah, thats pretty awesome really